# ListView randomly selecting CheckBoxes onItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView where each ListItem keeps a CheckBox in it's layout. I want the CheckBoxes to be activated when their ListItems are clicked. The problem is whenever i click a ListItem the CheckBoxes are randomly activated. For example: I click on ListItem1 and the CheckBox of ListItem4 is activated. And so on. How can i prevent this? Here is my OnItemClickListener:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, R.id.listcontent, valueslist);

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb); 
if (cb.isChecked() == false) {
cb.setChecked(true); 
} else {
cb.setChecked(false); 
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb);
```

you should be using

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
```

Edit: 
Declare a class like below and then use CArrayAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter. Give it a try. Might work

Use this

```
   private class CArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public CArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    CheckBox cb =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb);
    cb.setChecked(false);
    return view;

}

}
```

Comment: This only causes 2 CheckBoxes to be randomly activated.

Comment: It has to do with ListView Recycling. Usually the adapter to make things fast will use the same View for multiple rows

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: what kind of adapter is it? Have you written the getView of adapter. Posting the adapter code will help

Comment: I've added the code to my first post. I haven't written the getView of the adapter.